Button style different behavious tailwind css
<button 
  className="rounded-full font-semibold mr-4 text-slate-200 px-4 border-[1.5px]">
  Edit Profile
</button>

With this code, I get different result from when I use it on my app and in tailwind CSS sandbox


How did this happen, and how to solve this

Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a Stack Snippet using the <> icon.  See How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example

Have you compared the tailwind config of the sandbox with your own environment?
